# how to set multiple value for same name in option tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jsp

I want to set multiple values of same id or same names in option tag. In my form contains Subjects Field that with Plus(+) and Minus Button(-) to add or remove fields(fields are not constant).

I have attached Image for your refernce @ http://s26.postimg.org/n59ryciah/Stack_cip_subject.png

If i choose Class Name,subjects Fields are automatically filled by AJAX. In this above Picture i set same id,names for all subject fileds. How to set values for all fields.

My Code:

**JSP:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="subjects" id="subjectSelect" ></select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
subjectSelect += "<option selected=\"selected\" disabled>Select a Subject</option>";
_.each(jsonResponse,function(row){
subjectSelect += "<option value="+row.id+">"+row.subjectName+"</option>";
});
$("#subjectSelect").html(subjectSelect);
```

**My problem** This id will set for first field only. I want to set values for all fields. How to set it?

Comment: id values must be unique.

Comment: ok. how to set values for all fields?

Answer (score 1):

i have a bit different answer, but it would do similar thing:
in your html:

```
  <button onclick="addId(); return false;">Add Id</button>
```

this where you want to add your buttons:

```
 <div id="buttons"> </div>
```

between `<script></script>` tags:

```
var answers = 0,
write = document.getElementById('buttons');

function addID() {
     write.innerHTML += '<input type="text" id="answer"' + answers + '/> <br />';
answers++;
}​
```